# Removing an Object from a Linked List Based on Level

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception, linked-list

So basically what I'm trying to do is have a boss spawn (ever 10 levels) and have every other enemy currently on screen removed. All object are in a linkedlist and extend GameObject.

In GameObject I have removed as a boolean and:

```
public GameObject(float x, float y, ID id) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.removed = removed;
    this.id = id;
}
```

Going off another suggestion from a previous thread, in the handler I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
         if (object.get(i).removed == true)
              object.remove(i);
    }
```

The way I'm checking the level and removing the enemy is (basic enemy line 41) This is in the basic enemies class:

```
if(hud.level % 10 == 0) {
        this.removed = true;
    }
```

Every time I run the code and an enemy spawns in it throws a nullPointerException at line 41 of basic enemy. Full error is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at BasicEnemy.tick(BasicEnemy.java:41)
at Handler.tick(Handler.java:13)
at Game.tick(Game.java:92)
at Game.run(Game.java:73)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

The int level is public and set to 1 at the start

I'm not very good with LinkedLists so this is pretty confusing atm.

*edit*

hud.level is

```
public int level = 1;
```

HUD is the class which keeps track of overlays, current level, and score the code for increasing score and level is:

```
public void tick() {

    HEALTH = Game.clamp(HEALTH, 0, 100);
    greenValue = Game.clamp(greenValue, 0, 255);

    greenValue = HEALTH * 2;

    score++;

}
```

Level:

```
public void tick() {
    scoreKeep ++;

    if(scoreKeep >= 100) {
        scoreKeep = 0;
        hud.setLevel(hud.getLevel() + 1);
```

Comment: What is `hud` and `hud.level`?

Comment: What is the type of `removed` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling `this.removed = true;`, we know this is a `boolean` or a `Boolean`. I

```
public GameObject(float x, float y, ID id) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.removed = removed; // ####
    this.id = id;
}
```

But you don't have a `removed` parameter, so it is the same as `this.removed = this.removed` or the same as not doing it.

Now, there is two possibitlies for `removed` type :.

- a `boolean` default `false`
- a `Boolean`, default `null`

Calling `object.get(i).removed == true` would trigger a `NullPointerException` if this is a `Boolean` (because of the out boxing from `Boolean` to a `boolean`).

FYI:

The loop to removed every flag value could be changed to use [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) that takes a predicate (here, the getter returning a boolean) to remove every flagged items (the method iterate the collection)

```
object.removeIf(GamObject::isRemoved)
```

Assuming you have a getter `public boolean isRemoved()` in `GameObject`.